# For every $b>0$ and $b^2>a^2$, then $ -b<a<b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
0_\mathbb F<b\in\mathbb F\qquad\forall a\in\mathbb F\qquad a^2<b^2\Rightarrow-b<a<b
$$
I've tried splitting the problem into cases:
if a=0:
$$
a^2=0=a\\
-b<0=a<b
$$
if a<0:
$$
a<0\\
0<b\\
a<b
$$
if 0<a:
$$
0<a\\
0<b\\
-b<0\\
-b<a
$$
The problem is that I can't find a way to justify the second part of the two last inequalities (-b<a and a<b), to prove the statement.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Just a field that complies with field axioms.

Comment: $b^2-a^2 \gt 0 \implies (b+a)(b-a) \gt 0$ that should do it.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2<b^2\Rightarrow b^2-a^2>0 \Rightarrow  (b-a)(b+a)>0 \Rightarrow  $

$b-a,b+a>0$  or $b-a,b+a <0$

In the first case $-b<a<b$ and in the second case $b<a<-b$.

The second case is not accepted since $0<b \Rightarrow  0<b<a<-b \Rightarrow  -b >0 \Rightarrow  b<0$ contradiction

Comment: Yes of course, it was a typo